# Comparision with text file to check whether given word is present or not usin BST and input from text file

Tags: c++, string, char, binary-search-tree

I am making a simple word comparison program.

For this, I have a list of words in a text file with one word per line.

Then, I imported all these words into a program using ifstream and then into BST.

Then, I used to insert, create the root, search and traversal functions.

But, I am getting these two simple errors which I don't understand at all/.

Please help!

I used a BST to store all the words from txt file into program and then search among them. I also included the option of adding new words directly to program but not txt file.

I am having the following errors:

"
In function void create()

> incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char[100]'

In function void insert()

> incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char[100]'

"

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char x;
    char a[100];
    int count=0,i=0;
    char str;
struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char word[100];
};
struct node *root=NULL;
void create()
{
    struct node *newnode;
    newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    char str[100];

    for(i=0;i<=100;i++) {
        str= a[i];
        }

    strcpy(newnode->word,str);
    newnode->left=NULL;
    newnode->right=NULL;
    root=newnode;
}
void insert()
{
    struct node *newnode,*temp,*parent;
    newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    char str[100];
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++) {
        str= a[i];
        }


    strcpy(newnode->word,str);
    newnode->left=NULL;
    newnode->right=NULL;
    temp=root;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        parent=temp;
        if(strcmp(temp->word,str)<0)
            temp=temp->left;
        else
            temp=temp->right;
    }
    if(strcmp(parent->word,str)<0)
        parent->left=newnode;
    else
        parent->right=newnode;
}
void traverse(struct node *temp)
{
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
        traverse(temp->right);
        cout<<temp->word<<":";
        traverse(temp->left);
    }
}
void search()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=root;
    char ab[100];
    cout<<"enter the word to search \n";
    cin>>ab;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(temp->word,ab)==0)
        {
            cout<<"element found \n";
            break;
        }
        else if(strcmp(temp->word,ab)<0)
        {
            temp=temp->left;
        }
        else if(strcmp(temp->word,ab)>0)
        {
            temp=temp->right;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"not found";
        }

    }

}
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("test.txt");


    if(inFile.fail()) {

    cerr << "Error opening file"<< endl ;

    exit(1);

    }

    char x;
    char a[100];
    int count=0,i=0;
    char str;

    while( !inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> x;
            a[i]=x;
            count++;
            i++;
            }

    for (i=0;i<100;i++){
    cout<< a[i]<<endl;
    }


    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"***menu***\n1.cerate root node\n2.insert a word\n3.traverse\n4.search\n6.Exit\n";
        cout<<"enter your choice \n";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                create();
                break;
            case 2:
                insert();
                break;
            case 3:
                traverse(root);
                break;
            case 4:
                search();
                break;
            case 6:
                exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `new` and `delete`, not `malloc` and `free` when writing C++ code and `std::string` instead of `char` arrays (you even included `<string>`!)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `str` has type `char[100]` and `a[i]` has type `char`.  You cannot assign one to the other. Maybe you meant `str[i] = a[i]` instead. But I don't understand what you are trying to do with this anyway. You can use`strcpy(newnode->word, a);` directly.

Comment: I am trying to assign the word from text file to BST.

Comment: a[i] is the word from text file. Where as str is the one in BST.